# Exporting Plot with Filling creates unwanted Outline around Filling

Tags: bugs, export, pdf-format, filling, opacity

**Bug introduced in 12 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0**  [CASE:4899765]

---

The following code generates a plot that has a faint outline around the top, left, and right boundaries of the filling. In *Mathematica* (13.0.0.0, Mac) itself, the outline is not present. It only appears when exporting.

How can I remove this outline?

```
Export[
    "test.pdf",
    Plot[
        Sin[x],
        {x, 0, 2 Pi},
        Filling -> Top
    ]
]
```

The outline also appears when exporting `Graphics` of `Polygon`s and similar shapes.

[image: screenshot of the PDF]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about getting rid of the `Opacity` in the filling?:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Top, 
 FillingStyle -> Blend[{White, ColorData[97][1]}, 0.2]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, "test.pdf"}], %];
First@Import[%]
```

[image]

Comment: A solution that respects the Opacity would be nice to have, but this works for my current use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I reproduce the problem with versions 13.0.0 and 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64, but not with version 8.0.4 on the same machine.

The issue happens when we `Export` to PDF a `Graphics` object containing a `Rectangle` or `Polygon` primitive with `Opacity` directive. A minimal example:

```
gr = Graphics[{Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[]}];
Export["test.pdf", gr] // SystemOpen
```

In the exported file opened by Adobe Acrobat Reader the rectangle has an unwanted outline:

[image: screenshot]

To explore the problem deeper, I define an auxiliary function that exports supplied expression to PDF, and then immediately imports the results as vector graphics:

```
vectorExportImportPDF[expr_] :=
  First@ImportString[ExportString[expr, "PDF", "AllowRasterization" -> False],
    If[$VersionNumber >= 12.2, {"PDF", "PageGraphics"}, {"PDF", "Pages"}],
    "TextOutlines" -> False];
```

Apply it to the above `Graphics`:

```
vectorExportImportPDF[gr] // ResourceFunction["ShortInputForm"]
```

[image: screenshot]

We see that imported graphics contains an explicit outline defined via `JoinedCurve`. We can see the outline alone if we remove the `FilledCurve` object:

```
vectorExportImportPDF[gr] /. _FilledCurve -> {}
```

[image: screenshot]

Apparently, it is a bug. Reported to the support as [CASE:4899765].

---

> A solution that respects the `Opacity` would be nice to have

A workaround is to `Export` a `FilledCurve`, but not `Rectangle` or `Polygon` primitive:

```
gr2 = vectorExportImportPDF[gr] /. _JoinedCurve -> {};

vectorExportImportPDF[gr2] // ShortInputForm
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm curious how did you test with different versions? Did you just install  and uninstall them to test?

Comment: @hana Usually I have several versions installed at the same time.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you can do that.