# How to remove the outline overlapping with grid?

Tags: plotting, bugs, export, pdf-format, opacity

**Bug introduced in 12 or earlier and persisting through 13.1.0 [CASE:4899765]**

---

How can I remove the outline in my export PDF here which seems to be caused by the overlapping of the shape and the grid lines?

[image]

It doesn't seem to show on the Mathematica image (or just because I couldn't zoom in enough) but when I exported PDF and zoom in I can see it.

```
polygon = {{1, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}}
image = ListLinePlot[polygon, 
    GridLines -> {Range[1, 5, 1/2], Range[0, 5, 1/2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, {0, 5}}, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}, 
    FillingStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.2], Orange], 
    GridLines -> {Range[1, 5, 1], Range[1, 5, 1]}, ImageSize -> 250, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, 
    Frame -> {{None, Automatic}, {Automatic, None}}] /. _Line -> 
    Sequence[];
Export["image.pdf", image]
```

This is the output in my 13.0.1 version which is even worse than the 12.1 version. I'm going to check for the update. 
 I checked for the update but unfortunately we here we don't have the latest version for support. Is there any way to work around this?

[image]

Comment: @cvgmt I think I have the same problem in my 13.1 version. The above is from 12.1.1 in my PC but with I had the same problem yesterday in a 13.1 version on a different computer.

Comment: Anyway I'll check it again when I get to my 13.1 version. Is there any fix for the 12.1?

Comment: You can make the grid lines non-transparent, and apply the option "GridLinesInFront" (search for it on the site).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov what do you mean non-transparent grid lines? What seems to be opposite with what I'm trying to do now. I want to show the grid lines but I don't want to show the outline around the orange region as in the image above.

Comment: You question formulation is a bit misleading. If the problem is not with grid lines, but with the region, you could try to adjust the style of the region boundary using the PlotStyle option.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I don't think so? I did remove the region boundary with `_Line -> 
    Sequence[]` already but somehow it still appears when I export to pdf.

Comment: This is a known bug. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262617/280

Comment: With version 13.1.0 on Win10 x64 I reproduce the bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH8ZR.png

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov  likely so but I'll check if it works for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### UPDATE

Here is a universal version of `polygon2FilledCurve` which should work correctly independently of the presence of `GraphicsComplex` inside of `Graphics`:

```
polygon2FilledCurve = # /. 
     g_GraphicsComplex :> (g /. {
         Polygon[pts : {{__Integer} ..}] :> FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[pts]],
         Polygon[pts : {__Integer}] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]}) /.
    {Polygon[pts : {_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) ..}] :> FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[pts]],
     Polygon[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ]] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;
```

(original version below works incorrectly in more complicated cases than the one given in the OP, as was found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270414/280).)

---

### Original answer

Your problem is not related to grid lines, it is just the known [bug with exporting `Polygon` primitive to PDF format](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262648/280). The workaround is to represent the `Polygon` as a `FilledCurve` object which doesn't suffer from the bug:

```
polygon2FilledCurve = # /. {
     Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 3] :> FilledCurve[Thread[Line[pts]]],         
     Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 2] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;

Export["image.pdf", polygon2FilledCurve[image]] // SystemOpen
```

Here is how exported figure is rendered by Adobe Acrobat:

[image: screenshot]