# Why does polygon2FilledCurve not work here?

Tags: export, pdf-format, conversion

From my [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270159/how-to-remove-the-outline-overlapping-with-grid) thread where @Alexey Popkov proposed `polygon2FilledCurve` to remove the outline when exporting to PDF. Now I'm trying  to apply that to this but it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

```
polygon2FilledCurve = # /. {Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 3] :> 
      FilledCurve[Thread[Line[pts]]], 
     Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 2] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;
polygon = {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {5, 5}, {5, 0}, {-5, 0}, {-5, 5}, {-4, 
    3}, {0, 1}};
image = ListLinePlot[polygon, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}] /. _Line -> 
   Sequence[]
```

`Export["image.pdf", polygon2FilledCurve[image]`

This is the image:

[image]
However, the exported PDF image is not correct.

[image]

I'm looking for a solution which work for many types of polygon.

Comment: @Michael sorry I fogot to add the export code.

Comment: Thanks!........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the `GraphicsComplex` style polygon to a normal, coordinate-point one:

```
gcpolyToNormal = # /. 
    GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o___] :> 
     GraphicsComplex[p, 
      g /. Polygon[v_] :> Polygon[v /. i_Integer :> p[[i]]]] &;

polygon2FilledCurve = # /. {Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 4] :> 
      FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[pts]], 
     Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 3] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;
polygon = {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {5, 5}, {5, 0}, {-5, 0}, {-5, 5}, {-4, 
    3}, {0, 1}};
image = ListLinePlot[polygon, Filling -> {1 -> Axis}] /. _Line -> 
   Sequence[]
Export["image.pdf", polygon2FilledCurve[gcpolyToNormal@image]]
```

[image]

(I always add "/tmp/" to my test filenames, but it doesn't work on Windows, I think.)

Alternatively, one can fix `polygon2FilledCurve` for `GraphicsComplex`:

```
polygon2FilledCurve = # /. {Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 2] :> 
      FilledCurve[Thread[Line[pts]]], 
     Polygon[pts_ /; Depth[pts] == 1] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;
```

But then you have to decide which way you want it. Or one could write a more complicated function that parsed the polygons to see if they were "normal" or `GraphicsComplex` type.

Here's a way to convert polygons in `GraphicsComplex` to filled curves without converting them to normal form:

```
gcpolyToFilledCurved = # /. 
    GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o___] :> GraphicsComplex[p, g /. {
        Polygon[v : {__Integer}] :> FilledCurve[Line[v]],
        Polygon[v : {{__Integer} ..}] :> 
         FilledCurve[Thread@Line[v]]}] &;
```

I see @AlexeyPopkov had already posted something like this, plus a fix to the `polygon2FilledCurve` from the OP.  I was called to dinner before I finished my edit.

Comment: If you want more rigorous checking, this checks whether the polygon is in the proper form for a `GraphicsComplex`: `gcpolyToNormal = # /. GraphicsComplex[p_, g_, o___] :> GraphicsComplex[p, g /. Polygon[v_?(VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] || AllTrue[#, VectorQ[#, IntegerQ] &] &)] :> Polygon[v /. i_Integer :> p[[i]]]] &;`

Comment: Actually your solution won't do the trick because after applying `gcpolyToNormal` we have `Depth[pts] == 4`, and `polygon2FilledCurve` won't be applied. The same mistake is with your "fix" for `polygon2FilledCurve`. See also my answer.

Comment: Please check the output of updated `polygon2FilledCurve[gcpolyToNormal@image]` - it is as shown in the question due to the reasons explained in my answer. All cases of `FilledCurve[Thread@Line[v]]` should be replaced with `FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[v]]`.

Comment: Here is what I get: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChJxM.png).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Sorry, I've got bad eyes and misread which thing to fix.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The problem arises in the first place because the original version of `polygon2FilledCurve` used the single-component multi-segment syntax form of `FilledCurve` instead of its multi-component single-segment syntax form. Also, `FilledCurve`'s filling behavior for overlapping components differs from the one for `Polygon`, hence for the conversion purposes we must use only the single-component single-segment syntax form. Here is a universal version of `polygon2FilledCurve` which should work correctly independently of the presence of `GraphicsComplex` inside of `Graphics`:

```
polygon2FilledCurve = # /. 
     g_GraphicsComplex :> (g /. {
         Polygon[pts : {{__Integer} ..}] :> FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[pts]],
         Polygon[pts : {__Integer}] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]}) /.
    {Polygon[pts : {_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &) ..}] :> FilledCurve /@ Thread[Line[pts]],
     Polygon[pts_ /; MatrixQ[pts, NumericQ]] :> FilledCurve[Line[pts]]} &;
```

I've updated my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270175/280) in the linked thread with this implementation.

---

More info about the syntax and the use cases of `FilledCurve` can be found in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/646/280) answer.