# Weird PDF (also EPS and SVG) exported graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, bugs, export, pdf-format

I'm producing a graphic (sorry for not posting the code but it's quite disordered (see edit below)) and would like to export it as a vector image. For some reason the PDF (below left) does not look very much like the one I see in the notebook (right) (only corrected when exporting to .png or .jpg.)

[image] [image]

I tried to search in previous post but up to now, despite many related troubles, I have not found a quick solution.

(I'm working with Mathematica 12.3.1.0 on MW 64-bit platform)

**EDIT** The following is a simplified version of the drawing but with exactly the same issue.

```
\[CapitalOmega] = Disk[{0, 0}];
circ = ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], AspectRatio -> 1, PlotStyle -> Gray, BoundaryStyle -> Black]
```

so when I use

```
Export["path\\gra.pdf", circ, "PDF"]
```

I get the "dark" picture as before (or as shown below), instead of the "light" one that I see in the notebook.

[image][image]

Comment: I don't know how you think we could possibly help you without the code that generate that image, as well as mention of your version of Mathematica and of your operating system.

Comment: @MarcoB True. As for the version, it is 12.3.1.0. The code is really messy, so I'll try to paste it if no generic answer is eventually given, but I'd prefer to avoid it. Let me just mention that I've gotten similar results when exporting several kinds of plots in PDF format. Thank you.

Comment: Please prepare a minimal working example reproducing this behavior. If not, the question will be closed.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov OK, thanks. I added the necessary material.

Comment: Confirm it (both pdf and eps) in 13.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @DanielCastro See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps?rq=1)

Comment: I reproduce the problem with versions 12.3.1 and 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64. Please report it to the support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduce the bug with versions 12.3.1 and 13.1.0 on Windows 10 x64. Please report it to the support.

Here is a fix:

```
circFixed = 
 circ /. Polygon[pts : {{__Integer} ..}] :> FilledCurve[List /@ Thread[Line[pts]]]
Export["gra.pdf", circFixed] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

Actually, we have two bugs here:

1. [Exporting `Polygon` primitive to PDF format results in addition of unwanted outline.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/262617/280)
2. Exporting of a group of `FilledCurve`s (which is [the most direct fix for the bug #1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270175/280)) to PDF format gives unwanted tiny white lines between them. This doesn't happen when we export them as one `FilledCurve` object using the *multi-component single-segment* syntax form of `FilledCurve` as recommended [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/646/280). The latter approach is implemented in the fix I provided above. It works well in this concrete case. However, this solution isn't correct in the general case, because this syntax form will create holes where the components overlap, what we don't want because the multi-component syntax form of `Polygon` doesn't have this feature.